# Step response of feedback system

Tags: matlab, control-systems

We have a feedback system F(s) as in this figure:

[image]

[image: G(s)]

and this is the step response of G(s):

[image]

and H=10.

F(s):

[image]

We got the root locus of the system F(s) as this:

[image]

then we determined the gain at marginal stability:

[image]

which is equal to 2.5.

Then, we made H = 2.57 (slightly larger than 2.5) and we obtained the step response of the new system Fh(s). Here is it with the step response of the original system F(s):

[image]

Then, we made H = 2.43 (slightly lower than 2.5) and we obtained the step response of the new system Fl(s). Here is it with the step response of the original system F(s):

[image]

My questions:

- What can we know from the step response plot of G(s)?
- What can we know from the step response plot of F(s)?
- When we changed the gain to 2.57, how did the system F(s) change? What can we conclude by comparing the step responses of F(s) and Fh(s)?
- When we changed the gain to 2.43, how did the system F(s) change? What can we conclude by comparing the step responses of F(s) and Fl(s)?

Answer (score 1):

- G(s) is unstable because the step-response doesn't have a steady-state value. It goes to infinity.
- F(s) is stable since its step response has a steady-state value near 0.1. It's underdamped response.
- Fh(s) is stable since its step response has a steady-state value near 0.2. It's underdamped response with more oscillations than F(s).
- Fl(s) is unstable because it doesn't have a steady-state value. It has a very large oscillations that start after some time.